# Conditional redirect not working in else condition

Tags: php, redirect

We have an old URL that we're wanting to redirect via PHP to a new location. (Please no lectures on whether this is the best way to do it; it's what's been decided.)

If a user goes to http://oldurl.com, we want to redirect to http://newurl.com. If they go to http://oldurl.com/locations/illinois/12345 (or any other location-based url of this format) we want to redirect to http://newurl.com/locations/illinois/12345.

```
<?php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);


if(is_array($segments) && in_array("locations", $segments)) {
    header('Location: http://newurl.com/locations/' . $segments[2] . '/' . $segments[3]);
}
else {
    header('Location: http://newurl.com');
}
```

The `if` condition works - it redirects to the dynamically-built url. But when a user goes to http://oldurl.com, instead of hitting the else condition and redirecting to http://newurl.com, it stays on the original url and serves a blank page.

Any idea why?

Comment: Try looking at the error log. Blank page typically means 500 error and something will be written to the error log.

Comment: blank page may mean errors. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - use that and to either log or display, then come back and tell us what it is, if there's an error.

Comment: `var_dump($segments);` on your page. And see if you have anything in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on you main page.

Comment: That's the strange part - no errors in the log. And I've already done the echoing of `$segments`; it contains what I expect it to contain.

Comment: Have you tried doing an `exit` after each `header` otherwise it seems to work for me. I am guessing the code continues to do other things after the code you have shown

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I haven't tried using an `exit`; I'll give that a shot. And no - the code doesn't do anything after what I've shown - that's the complete code.

Comment: Then thats probably not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`is_array` will always return `true` in this instance because a path, no matter what, even if it is the root directory, there is a / at the beginning. This will cause the string to split like this `[0]/[1]`

If your `REQUEST_URI` is /, you will get an array with 2 entries that are both equal to `""`

This should work.

```
<?php
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
    if(!(count($segments) == 2) && !(in_array("", $segments))) {
        header('Location: http://order.pizzahut.com/locations/' . $segments[2] . '/' . $segments[3]);
    }
    else {
        header('Location: http://order.pizzahut.com');
    }
```

If I am not missing something, this should work.

Comment: `with 2 entries` - with one entry. `""`.

Comment: `is_array($segments)` may always return `true` in this code, but `in_array("locations", $segments)` will not.

Comment: @u_mulder no, I have tested this in my code. It returns 2 entries because a request to the document_root will return `/` This causes the array to return two results, an empty string before and after the `/`

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
<?php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'];
if (substr($url, 0, 7) == "http://")
$url = substr($url, 7, $url.length);

$segments = explode('/', $url, 2);

if(is_array($segments)) {
    header('Location: http://order.pizzahut.com/' . $segments[1]);
}
else {
    header('Location: http://order.pizzahut.com');
}
```

Instead of splitting the URL in many strings, you can split in the first ocurrence of a slash `/`, after the `http://`